# URL issue which is displaying port no

Tags: php, mysql

In my aws my site is running on port 8000 due to which in `my url 8000 (www.example.com:8000)`is visible . i want to remove it is should look like `www.example.com`.

**I have  tried this:**

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example[12].com):8080$ [NC] RewriteRule
>   ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a proxy on your server. There is a really good tutorial at apache.org, using an Apache Web Server.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

This enables you to connect to your server via port 80, which is not printed in the url bar of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using IP tables in linux with redirecting requests from from one port to other, please follow the below syntax to achieve.

Syntax

The syntax is as follows to redirect tcp $srcPortNumber port to $dstPortNumber:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport $srcPortNumber -j REDIRECT --to-port $dstPortNumber`

The syntax is as follows to redirect udp $srcPortNumber port to $dstPortNumber:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport $srcPortNumber -j REDIRECT --to-port $dstPortNumber`

Replace eth0 with your actual interface name. The following syntax match for source and destination ips:

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src $SRC_IP_MASK --dst $DST_IP -p tcp --dport $portNumber -j REDIRECT --to-ports $rediectPort`

Comment: Problem is with ip table is that we need to constantly work on server (restart the server) due to which ip table comes to its default state.